# Ionic user token

Tags: ionic-framework, push

I want to add a push token to an user in my application. I have the push token, I have the user, but I can't add the token to the user. How I can add the push token to this user?

Here is the code:

```
var io = Ionic.io();

username = localStorage.getItem('username');

var signupSuccess = function(user) {
  // The user was authenticated; you can get the authenticated user

  console.log(user);
};

var signupFailure = function(errors) {
  for (var err in errors) {
    // Check the error and provide an appropriate message
    // for your application.
    user = Ionic.User.current();
  }
};
var details = {

  'email': 'email@gmail.com',
  'password': 'pass2',
  'username': 'username'
}


Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(signupSuccess, signupFailure);

var push = new Ionic.Push();
var user = Ionic.User.current();

var callback = function(pushToken) {

  alert('TOKEN: ' + pushToken.token);

  user.addPushToken(pushToken);

  user.save(); // You NEED to call a save after you add the token
}

push.register(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest one thing. You can ask the backend or server to team add a user token in the database or else.

You can manually add the following thing if it is an JSON object:

```
user["token"]=value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer `user.addPushToken(pushToken);`

Instead you need:

```
push.register(function(token) {
    push.saveToken(token);
});
```

This will automatically add the token to the currently logged in Ionic user.

See this [example from Ionic documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-full-setup#section-3-5-add-some-push-code)

N.B. as you're adding this at the point that the user is signing in, you also need to add the above code to register for push inside your `$ionicPlatform.ready` function:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
    var push = new Ionic.Push();
    push.register(function(token) {
        push.saveToken(token);
    });
});
```

Or more likely, create one function to register for push which is called both from within $ionicPlatform.ready and also from within your signup / signin functions.

Otherwise, if Push has not been registered inside `$ionicPlatform.ready`, it won't add the token to your user when you call `push.saveToken` after signup / signin.